# Font Awesome inside Ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome

I had a ruby function in my productions_helper.rb:

```
def new_applications(number, new_castings_for_user)
  content_tag :span, "(#{number})", class: "icon-new-applications#{' highlight' if new_castings_for_user}"
end
```

I added a font awesome icon to it:

```
def new_applications(number, new_castings_for_user)
  content_tag :span, "(#{number})", fa_icon: "user-plus", class: "icon-new-applications#{' highlight' if new_castings_for_user}"
end
```

However, the icon is not showing up on my website. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're not actually rendering the icon. In your code all you're doing is adding an attribute of `fa_icon` to the span tag. Unless there is some additional code that will interpret this attribute, it won't work. Try this instead

```
def new_applications(number, new_castings_for_user)
  content_tag :span, class: "icon-new-applications#{' highlight' if new_castings_for_user}" do
    [content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-user-plus"), "(#{number})"].join.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: This works. However, it gets rid of the "(#{number})"

Comment: Oops forgot about that. Please see my edited answer.